# fscanf doesn't recognise delimeters defined in format string (

Tags: c, parsing, format, scanf, format-string

I'm trying to read user login data (username, password, some integer, security answer) from a file and store it in a linked list. The file validation.txt holds the data for all users, where each user has a line of its own holding all of the fields for that user in the format (no spaces):

user1_$_ password1 _$_42 _$_answer1

user2_$_ password2 _$_21 _$_answer2

The various fields are to be stored as members of a struct (named 'user') that comprises the linked list (each struct also has a member "next" which points to the next user in the list.

I trying to use fscanf to parse each line and save the info directly into the structs, but for some reason, the fscanf doesn't pick up on *$* when it reaches them, and stores an entire line under the "username" member rather than just the string "user1". I have read loads online about the string format but can't figure this out. I played around trying to add whitespaces to the file and to the format string with many different outcomes that I didn't really understand why they are the way they are.. Based on what I read online the string should be read until a character present in the format string is reached, and it is then skipped over. This seems pretty straightforeward but why doesn't this work ?

My code:

```
user *loadUsers(){

    user *Users, *currPtr;
    FILE *fp = fopen("validation.txt", "r");
    if(fp==NULL||feof(fp)!=0){
        return NULL;
    }
    
    Users = (user *)malloc(sizeof(user));
    currPtr = Users;
    fscanf(fp, "%s_$_%s_$_%d_$_%s\n", currPtr->username, currPtr->password, &(currPtr->randomNum), currPtr->secAns);
    while(feof(fp)==0){
        currPtr->next = (user *)malloc(sizeof(user));
        currPtr = currPtr->next;
        fscanf(fp, "%s_$_%s_$_%d_$_%s\n", currPtr->username, currPtr->password, &(currPtr->randomNum), currPtr->secAns);
    }
    return Users;
}
```

Output:

When I iterate through my list after the call to this function and print just the username members of each struct, I get the whole line printed (username = user1_$_ password1 _$_42 _$_answer1 rather than just user1). Anyone know what's going on here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never, *ever*, call `*scanf()` without checking the return value.

`%s` matches any sequence of non-whitespace characters, i.e. `fscanf()` keeps matching that first `%s` and does not even "see" the following underscore in the format string.

You *could* work with `%[^_]` to match everything not an underscore, but generally speaking you are better off reading whole lines of input with `fgets()` and then parse the input in memory using the various string functions. `*scanf()` is rather limited in its ability to recover from malformed input.

Comment: Thanks for your reponse. If I understand correctly, any time I try to read a string, the portion of the format string that comes after %s won't matter at all because it would just consider any sequence of characters from the %s onwards to be a part of that string. Is that right ?

Comment: @Qman: [Check the documentation.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf). The format string is processed item by item. `%s` will match input until a whitespace is encountered. Only then will the next item in the format string be considered.